# Mistake in Apostol's Calculus vol. 1 Q9.6.12 complex conjugate proof

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I think there is a mistake in this problem. Apostol asks us to prove that: if $w=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ where $z$ is a complex number and $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, then $w-\overline{w}=(ad-bc)(z-\overline{z})/|cz+d|^2$.

I have found a solution where this result is found if $\overline{w}=(a\overline{z}+b)/(c\overline{z}+d)$. However, it can be proven that for any $z_1,z_2$, $(z_1/z_2)=(\overline{z_1}/\overline{z_2})$, which would make $w-\overline{w}=0$

I tried to solve it a different way by using the fact that $z_1*z_2=\overline{z_1}*\overline{z_2}$, to determine that $\overline{w}=(az+b)/(c\overline{z}+d)$, but I could not prove the desired result with this method.

Edit: There's a typo in my copy of Apostol. The left side of the quotient relation of complex numbers is supposed to be the conjugate of the entire quotient. This fixes it.

Comment: *Why* do you claim that $z_1/z_2=\overline{z_1}/\overline{z_2}$?

Comment: There's a typo in my copy of Apostol. The left side is supposed to be the conjugate of the entire quotient. This fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It can be proven"; no, it can't, unless $z_1/z_2$ is real.

Sometimes one needs to think less and just compute. As in this case.
\begin{align}
w-\bar w
&=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}-\frac{a\bar z+b}{c\bar z+d}=\frac{(az+b)(c\bar z+ d)-(a\bar z+b)(cz+d)}{(cz+d)(c\bar z +d)}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{bc(\bar z-z)+ad(z-\bar z)}{(cz+d)(\overline{c z +d})}
=\frac{(ad-bc)(z-\bar z)}{|cz+d|^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: There's a typo in my copy of Apostol. The left side is supposed to be the conjugate of the entire quotient. This fixes it.